# Program that runs docker image internally without user having to install docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is there a way to generate an executable of a project that pulls a docker image and prepare the enviroment without the user having to install anything but my program?

To give some example: Imagine that my program connects to some database, such as MongoDB or SQLite. I would use a docker image for the database. But i don't want the user to have to install docker or the database just to use the program.

The idea is that when the user installs the program I would pull the image and prepare the database, all in the background. The user doesn't have to know that the program is running a docker image and a database, they just want to use the program.

How can I approach this scenario? Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://silentinstallhq.com/docker-desktop-silent-install-how-to-guide/) will help

Comment: That's quite interesting. In this case i should be able to create an exe of my project that includes the docker installation